# Select multiple columns from different rows in one result in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I want to have in my results, a couple of columns from different table.
It looks like this:
[image]

And it has 4 rows.
unfortunately, i get everytime 4 results, 1 per every condition is met.
Let's say that I do left join by the first row, which is id 5 and then i want to include all the 4 rows as different values in my result set.
I tried with different IF condition but if onee of them is met, it skips the other IF conditions and creates like 20 results.

Comment: Provide sample data as textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (or create a fiddle). Provide desired output for this data. Specify precise MySQL version. Pictures are not useful.

Comment: As with java Object
I want to set all of these 4 rows into properties.
For example first one is ID,
second one is 4 types of different score for both teams.
i want to have all the 4 types into my java object when its run.
Now i get 4 different rows with all of these 4 combinations.